# Ranking of 1048 scores in Excel (From 1 to 0)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ranking-functions

As shown in the example image below, I have several columns with results from a social network analysis software. I am now looking for a way to assign a ranking, going from "1" for the highest score to "0" for the lowest, in between 0.9XX - 0.001. (Separately for each column). The excel has 1048 row entries/ Unique values for each column.

E.g. In column Q the ranking for the values in column C and so on.

So in the end the ranks can be added to find the overall rank 1..

The idea is that the ranks have uniform steps ...

Help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

[image: The Excel columns in question.]

Comment: What's wrong with `RANK`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in column Q:
=RANK.AVG(C2,C$2:C$1049)

That will give you the rank.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the comment.But I am looking for a way to rank them with values going from 1 down to 0. Or 100 to 0... and in between the ranks would be 0.99X - 0.001 ... or something alike. .. So they can be added up in the end.

Comment: Ok, try this:Q: =RANK.AVG(C2,C$2:C$1049, 1)/1048  The 1 in the last parameter sorts them ascending (highest value is 1).  Dividing by the number of entries ensure each are equidistant and ranging from 0 to 1.  You can also use RANK.EQ, but I think AVG will more accurately represent what you are trying to do when aggregating all this.